# Как сделать чтобы pynput реагировал на нажатие цифры 1?

Tags: python

Короче, надо чтобы кнопка 1 реагировала на нажатие, отдельно от моего кода она работает, а в моем она просто игнорирует нажатие

Та что работает:

```
if key == keyboard.Key.esc and 'esc' not in pressed_keys:
    pressed_keys.add('esc')
    esc["bg"] = "red"
```

Та что не работает:

```
if key.char == '1':
    pressed_keys.add('C1')
    C1["bg"] = "red"
```

если что я в коде новичок и это писала нейросеть